# Cerrar Dialogo Modal con botón atras en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Las directivas de diseño de Google, especifican que si se muestra un cuadro de dialogo, el usuario en caso de querer cerrarlo, lo pueda realizar usando la pulsación del botón atrás.

**Definición del dialogo**

```
public static class MyDialogFragment2 extends DialogFragment   {
    private static final String TAG = "MyDialogFragment2";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateDialog: ");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Simple Dialog");
        builder.setMessage("Some message here");

        builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Positive");
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: Negative");
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

**Llamada del dialogo forma modal**

```
MyDialogFragment2 myDiag = new MyDialogFragment2();
myDiag.setCancelable(false);
myDiag.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "Diag2");
```

¿Cómo se puede implementar eso usando `DialogFragment` para los cuadros de dialogo llamados en modal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podrías sobre escribir el método de `onBackPressed()` en tu actividad

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    if(dialog.isVisible()){
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

sólo tendrías que hacer tu variable de `dialog` global.

Answer (score 0):

En [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307858/detect-back-button-but-dont-dismiss-dialogfragment) he encontrado una solución.

Sobrecargar el evento `onResume` del la clase del dialogo

```
public static class MyDialogFragment2 extends DialogFragment {
...
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    getDialog().setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(android.content.DialogInterface dialog,
                             int keyCode, android.view.KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == android.view.KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {
                // To dismiss the fragment when the back-button is pressed.
                dismiss();
                return true;
            }
            // Otherwise, do nothing else
            else return false;
        }
    });
}
```